# What is the second "state" in "ip link show" output

Tags: linux, networking, iproute2

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default 
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
```

The `UP` between the brackets means my link is operationnally up. But what does the `state UNKNOWN` mean ?

I went through this [doc](http://www.policyrouting.org/iproute2.doc.html#ss9.1.2) but could not find anything related to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, `lo` is a loopback device that doesn't have a hardware-relatable state, whereas `eth0` does.

```
superuser@hermes:~$ ip link show up
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 0a:00:00:00:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Answer (score 1):

The first one means the interface is administratively/logically up. The second one means it is acutally ready to send or receive packets. You can confirm this by "Link detect" field in `ethtool`